# How can I use the external library for the 2EDF7175F Gate Driver by Infineon in LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice, library

I want to simulate a circuit including the Infineon 2EDF7175F (Gate Driver) in LTSpice 17.
This is my circuit:

[image]

I created both the irfl024z (Mosfet) and the 2EDF7175F by opening the .lib in LTSpice and using the "create symbol" command. I've already tested the irfl024z in another simulation, and it worked flawlessly.
Once I start my simulation, I get the following message:

```
Unknown subcircuit called in:
   x:u2:dpwr:1 0«:0:agnd» u2:dpwr:dpwr0 u2:dpwr:dgnd0 u2:dpwr:dig_fpwr  voltage= 5  reference= 0 ".
```

Maybe somebody has experience with implementing Infineon PSpice libraries into LTSpice.

Comment: I don't see a .inc or .lib statement.

Answer (score 2):

[The Infineon webpage for the 2EDF7175F](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/gate-driver-ics/2edf7175f/) provides a [.zip file under the "Simulation Models" tab](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Gate_driver_2EDF7175F_EiceDRIVER_TINA_PSPICE_SIM-SimulationModels-v01_00-EN.zip?fileId=5546d46272e49d2a0173386679f66762) within the "Design Support" section.  Found inside the `.zip` file are directories geared towards different simulation programs.  If you look under the "PSpice" directory, there are two files in there:

- `2EDF7175F.lib`
- `BaseComps_PSpice.lib`

Your specific error message is saying it's looking for a subcircuit called `DIG_FPWR`.  This subcircuit is defined in `BaseComps_PSpice.lib`, and LTspice is either having trouble with it or it's tripping up LTspice's parsing of the text somewhere.  If you look at the SPICE error log <kbd>CTRL+L</kbd>, you can get a better idea of what's going on:

```
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model io_dig uio (  drvh=50 drvl=50  inld=0.0pf outld=0.0pf  atod1={}"atod_dig" atod2={}"atod_dig"  atod3={}"atod_dig" atod4={}"atod_dig"  dtoa1={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa2={}"dtoa_dig"  dtoa3={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa4={}"dtoa_dig"  tswhl1=0.5ns tswlh1=0.5ns  tswhl2=0.5ns tswlh2=0.5ns  tswhl3=0.5ns tswlh3=0.5ns  tswhl4=0.5ns tswlh4=0.5ns  digpower={}"dig_fpwr"  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model io_dig uio (  drvh=50 drvl=50  inld=0.0pf outld=0.0pf  atod1=()"atod_dig" atod2={}"atod_dig"  atod3={}"atod_dig" atod4={}"atod_dig"  dtoa1={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa2={}"dtoa_dig"  dtoa3={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa4={}"dtoa_dig"  tswhl1=0.5ns tswlh1=0.5ns  tswhl2=0.5ns tswlh2=0.5ns  tswhl3=0.5ns tswlh3=0.5ns  tswhl4=0.5ns tswlh4=0.5ns  digpower={}"dig_fpwr"  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model io_dig uio (  drvh=50 drvl=50  inld=0.0pf outld=0.0pf  atod1=()"atod_dig" atod2=()"atod_dig"  atod3={}"atod_dig" atod4={}"atod_dig"  dtoa1={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa2={}"dtoa_dig"  dtoa3={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa4={}"dtoa_dig"  tswhl1=0.5ns tswlh1=0.5ns  tswhl2=0.5ns tswlh2=0.5ns  tswhl3=0.5ns tswlh3=0.5ns  tswhl4=0.5ns tswlh4=0.5ns  digpower={}"dig_fpwr"  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model io_dig uio (  drvh=50 drvl=50  inld=0.0pf outld=0.0pf  atod1=()"atod_dig" atod2=()"atod_dig"  atod3=()"atod_dig" atod4={}"atod_dig"  dtoa1={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa2={}"dtoa_dig"  dtoa3={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa4={}"dtoa_dig"  tswhl1=0.5ns tswlh1=0.5ns  tswhl2=0.5ns tswlh2=0.5ns  tswhl3=0.5ns tswlh3=0.5ns  tswhl4=0.5ns tswlh4=0.5ns  digpower={}"dig_fpwr"  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model io_dig uio (  drvh=50 drvl=50  inld=0.0pf outld=0.0pf  atod1=()"atod_dig" atod2=()"atod_dig"  atod3=()"atod_dig" atod4=()"atod_dig"  dtoa1={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa2={}"dtoa_dig"  dtoa3={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa4={}"dtoa_dig"  tswhl1=0.5ns tswlh1=0.5ns  tswhl2=0.5ns tswlh2=0.5ns  tswhl3=0.5ns tswlh3=0.5ns  tswhl4=0.5ns tswlh4=0.5ns  digpower={}"dig_fpwr"  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model io_dig uio (  drvh=50 drvl=50  inld=0.0pf outld=0.0pf  atod1=()"atod_dig" atod2=()"atod_dig"  atod3=()"atod_dig" atod4=()"atod_dig"  dtoa1=()"dtoa_dig" dtoa2={}"dtoa_dig"  dtoa3={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa4={}"dtoa_dig"  tswhl1=0.5ns tswlh1=0.5ns  tswhl2=0.5ns tswlh2=0.5ns  tswhl3=0.5ns tswlh3=0.5ns  tswhl4=0.5ns tswlh4=0.5ns  digpower={}"dig_fpwr"  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model io_dig uio (  drvh=50 drvl=50  inld=0.0pf outld=0.0pf  atod1=()"atod_dig" atod2=()"atod_dig"  atod3=()"atod_dig" atod4=()"atod_dig"  dtoa1=()"dtoa_dig" dtoa2=()"dtoa_dig"  dtoa3={}"dtoa_dig" dtoa4={}"dtoa_dig"  tswhl1=0.5ns tswlh1=0.5ns  tswhl2=0.5ns tswlh2=0.5ns  tswhl3=0.5ns tswlh3=0.5ns  tswhl4=0.5ns tswlh4=0.5ns  digpower={}"dig_fpwr"  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model io_dig uio (  drvh=50 drvl=50  inld=0.0pf outld=0.0pf  atod1=()"atod_dig" atod2=()"atod_dig"  atod3=()"atod_dig" atod4=()"atod_dig"  dtoa1=()"dtoa_dig" dtoa2=()"dtoa_dig"  dtoa3=()"dtoa_dig" dtoa4={}"dtoa_dig"  tswhl1=0.5ns tswlh1=0.5ns  tswhl2=0.5ns tswlh2=0.5ns  tswhl3=0.5ns tswlh3=0.5ns  tswhl4=0.5ns tswlh4=0.5ns  digpower={}"dig_fpwr"  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model io_dig uio (  drvh=50 drvl=50  inld=0.0pf outld=0.0pf  atod1=()"atod_dig" atod2=()"atod_dig"  atod3=()"atod_dig" atod4=()"atod_dig"  dtoa1=()"dtoa_dig" dtoa2=()"dtoa_dig"  dtoa3=()"dtoa_dig" dtoa4=()"dtoa_dig"  tswhl1=0.5ns tswlh1=0.5ns  tswhl2=0.5ns tswlh2=0.5ns  tswhl3=0.5ns tswlh3=0.5ns  tswhl4=0.5ns tswlh4=0.5ns  digpower={}"dig_fpwr"  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model do_dig doutput (  s0name={}"0" s0vlo=-10.0 s0vhi=0.5  s2name={}"1" s2vlo=0.5 s2vhi=10.0  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model do_dig doutput (  s0name=()"0" s0vlo=-10.0 s0vhi=0.5  s2name={}"1" s2vlo=0.5 s2vhi=10.0  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model din_dig dinput (  s0name={}"0" s0tsw=1.0ns s0rlo=50 s0rhi=100k  s1name={}"1" s1tsw=1.0ns s1rlo=100k s1rhi=50  s2name={}"x" s2tsw=1.0ns s2rlo=110 s2rhi=100  s3name={}"r" s3tsw=1.0ns s3rlo=110 s3rhi=100  s4name={}"f" s4tsw=1.0ns s4rlo=110 s4rhi=100  s5name={}"z" s5tsw=1.0ns s5rlo=200k s5rhi=200k  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model din_dig dinput (  s0name=()"0" s0tsw=1.0ns s0rlo=50 s0rhi=100k  s1name={}"1" s1tsw=1.0ns s1rlo=100k s1rhi=50  s2name={}"x" s2tsw=1.0ns s2rlo=110 s2rhi=100  s3name={}"r" s3tsw=1.0ns s3rlo=110 s3rhi=100  s4name={}"f" s4tsw=1.0ns s4rlo=110 s4rhi=100  s5name={}"z" s5tsw=1.0ns s5rlo=200k s5rhi=200k  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model din_dig dinput (  s0name=()"0" s0tsw=1.0ns s0rlo=50 s0rhi=100k  s1name=()"1" s1tsw=1.0ns s1rlo=100k s1rhi=50  s2name={}"x" s2tsw=1.0ns s2rlo=110 s2rhi=100  s3name={}"r" s3tsw=1.0ns s3rlo=110 s3rhi=100  s4name={}"f" s4tsw=1.0ns s4rlo=110 s4rhi=100  s5name={}"z" s5tsw=1.0ns s5rlo=200k s5rhi=200k  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model din_dig dinput (  s0name=()"0" s0tsw=1.0ns s0rlo=50 s0rhi=100k  s1name=()"1" s1tsw=1.0ns s1rlo=100k s1rhi=50  s2name=()"x" s2tsw=1.0ns s2rlo=110 s2rhi=100  s3name={}"r" s3tsw=1.0ns s3rlo=110 s3rhi=100  s4name={}"f" s4tsw=1.0ns s4rlo=110 s4rhi=100  s5name={}"z" s5tsw=1.0ns s5rlo=200k s5rhi=200k  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model din_dig dinput (  s0name=()"0" s0tsw=1.0ns s0rlo=50 s0rhi=100k  s1name=()"1" s1tsw=1.0ns s1rlo=100k s1rhi=50  s2name=()"x" s2tsw=1.0ns s2rlo=110 s2rhi=100  s3name=()"r" s3tsw=1.0ns s3rlo=110 s3rhi=100  s4name={}"f" s4tsw=1.0ns s4rlo=110 s4rhi=100  s5name={}"z" s5tsw=1.0ns s5rlo=200k s5rhi=200k  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model din_dig dinput (  s0name=()"0" s0tsw=1.0ns s0rlo=50 s0rhi=100k  s1name=()"1" s1tsw=1.0ns s1rlo=100k s1rhi=50  s2name=()"x" s2tsw=1.0ns s2rlo=110 s2rhi=100  s3name=()"r" s3tsw=1.0ns s3rlo=110 s3rhi=100  s4name=()"f" s4tsw=1.0ns s4rlo=110 s4rhi=100  s5name={}"z" s5tsw=1.0ns s5rlo=200k s5rhi=200k  )"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Circuit: * Z:\Draft1.asc

Fatal Error: Unknown subcircuit called in:
   x:u1:dpwr:1 0«:0:agnd» u1:dpwr:dpwr0 u1:dpwr:dgnd0 u1:dpwr:dig_fpwr  voltage= 5  reference= 0
```

These are all syntax errors from the contents of `BaseComps_PSpice.lib`.  You have three PSpice device primitives here which are not compatible with LTspice: `uio`, `doutput`, and `dinput`.  It's possible to manually convert these to LTspice's proprietary "A-devices", but it could take quite a bit of work.

If you try using the SIMetrix library files found within the same `.zip` instead, you get similar problems but a lot less instances of them:

```
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model univ_dac dac_bridge  out_high={dout_high}  input_load=1p  t_rise=1n  t_fall=1n  g_pullup=0.02  g_pulldown=0.02  g_hiz=1e-9  knee_low ={dout_high*2.0/5}  knee_high ={dout_high*2.75/5}  v_smooth =0.5  in_family={}"univ""
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Questionable use of curly braces in ".model univ_adc adc_bridge  in_low={0.495*dout_high}  in_high={0.505*dout_high}  rise_delay=1e-12  fall_delay=1e-12  out_family ={}"univ"  out_low =0  out_high ={dout_high}  clamp_bias=0.5  clamp_res=10"
    Error: no expression present in: "[]"
Circuit: * Z:\Draft1.asc

Fatal Error: Too few nodes: aand1 [in1 in2] out d_and1
```

In this case, there are two SIMetrix primitives that are incompatible with LTspice: `dac_bridge` and `adc_bridge`.  I'm not sure if it'll be easier to convert these to LTspice instead of the PSpice ones.  I think at this point it might be best to contact Infineon and inquire about an LTspice-specific model.  If you look at where `BaseComps_PSpice.lib` gets `.lib`-ed within `2EDF7175F.lib`, you can see there's a `.LIB "BaseComps_LTSpice.lib"` commented out with an asterisk.  So it's possible they might already have an LTspice compatible version on hand???  I think it's at least worth asking their tech support about it.

```
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Include libraries for different versions of Spice:
* TINA
*.Lib "<TINADIR>\Spicelib\TINA_SMPS.lib"
* PSpice
.LIB "BaseComps_PSpice.lib"
* SIMetrix
*.LIB "BaseComps_SIMetrix.lib"
* LTSpice
*.LIB "BaseComps_LTSpice.lib"   <==========
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

I took a stab at modifying the subset of subcircuits used by `2EDF7175F` within `BaseComps_SIMetrix.lib` in order to be compatible with LTspice.  Below is my resultant `BaseComps_LTspice.lib`.  Within `2EDF7175F.lib` you have to comment out the SIMetrix library line and uncomment the LTspice one (as discussed above).  I haven't tested it beyond it running a basic `.op` analysis with minimal warnings (caused by how the `2EDF7175F` subcircuit was written).

```
********************************************
.Param MinADel=100p

.SUBCKT INV_P  IN OUT DPWR DGND
+ PARAMS:    DLH = 0 DHL = 0
*
.Param Cin= 1.0e-12
.Param Trc={Max((DLH),1N)}
.Param Tfc={Max((DHL),1N)}
C1 IN 0 {Cin}
A1 IN 0 0 0 0 OUT 0 0 BUF Trise={Trc} Tfall={Tfc}
.ENDS

.SUBCKT AND2_P  IN1 IN2 OUT DPWR DGND
+ PARAMS:    DLH = 0 DHL = 0
*
.Param Cin= 1.0e-12
.Param Trc={Max((DLH),1N)}
.Param Tfc={Max((DHL),1N)}
C1 IN1 0 {Cin}
C2 IN2 0 {Cin}
A1 IN1 IN2 0 0 0 0 OUT 0 AND Trise={Trc} Tfall={Tfc}
.ENDS

.SUBCKT AND3_P  IN1 IN2 IN3 OUT DPWR DGND
+ PARAMS:    DLH = 0 DHL = 0
*
.Param Cin= 1.0e-12
.Param Trc={Max((DLH),1N)}
.Param Tfc={Max((DHL),1N)}
C1 IN1 0 {Cin}
C2 IN2 0 {Cin}
C3 IN3 0 {Cin}
A1 IN1 IN2 IN3 0 0 0 OUT 0 AND Trise={Trc} Tfall={Tfc}
.ENDS

.SUBCKT BUF_P  IN OUT DPWR DGND
+ PARAMS:    DLH = 0 DHL = 0
*
.Param Cin= 1.0e-12
.Param Trc={Max((DLH),1N)}
.Param Tfc={Max((DHL),1N)}
C1 IN 0 {Cin}
A1 IN 0 0 0 0 0 OUT 0 BUF Trise={Trc} Tfall={Tfc}
.ENDS

.SUBCKT AD_BUF_P   IN OUT DPWR DGND
+ PARAMS:    DLH = 0 DHL = 0 IN_LOW=0.495 IN_HIGH=0.505
*
.Param Trc={Max((DLH),1N)}
.Param Tfc={Max((DHL),1N)}

*Gin 0 IN_ Value = {V(IN,DGND)/(ABS(V(DPWR,DGND)) + 1m)}
Gin 0 IN_ Value = {V(IN,DGND)}
Rin IN_ 0 1
A1 IN_ 0 0 0 0 0 OUT 0 SCHMITT Trise={Trc} Tfall={Tfc} Vt=0.5 Vh={(IN_HIGH-IN_LOW)/2}
.ENDS

.SUBCKT DA_BUF_P   IN OUT DPWR DGND
+ PARAMS:    DLH = 0 DHL = 0 OUT_LOW=0.0 OUT_HIGH=1.0 ROUT=1 COUT=1N
*
.Param Cin= 1.0e-12
.Param Trc={Max((DLH),1N)}
.Param Tfc={Max((DHL),1N)}
.Param Gout={1/(Abs(ROUT)+1m)}
*.Param COUT_={IF ( COUT > 1f, COUT, 0.1*Min(Trc,Tfc)/Max(ROUT,1m)) }
.Param COUT_={IF ( COUT > 1f, COUT, 0 ) }

Gout DGND OUT Value = {Gout*V(OUT_,0)}
Rout OUT DGND {ROUT}
Cout OUT DGND {COUT_}

C1 IN DGND {Cin}
A1 IN DGND DGND DGND DGND DGND OUT_ DGND BUF Vhigh={OUT_HIGH} Vlow={OUT_LOW} Trise={Trc} Tfall={Tfc} Rout={ROUT} Cout={COUT}
.ENDS

.subckt DIGIFPWR_NOOPNODE  AGND DPWR DGND
*+  optional: DPWR=$G_DPWR DGND=$G_DGND
*+  params:   VOLTAGE=5.0v REFERENCE=0v
+   params:   VOLTAGE={DOUT_HIGH} REFERENCE=0v
*
VDPWR  DPWR0 DGND0  {VOLTAGE}
R10     DPWR0 DGND0  1MEG
*VDGND  DGND0 AGND  {REFERENCE}
EVDGND  DGND0 0 Value= { V(AGND) +  REFERENCE }
R20     DGND0 0  1MEG
*VNC  G_NC AGND  
*R1 DPWR0 DPWR 1m
*R2 DGND0 DGND 1m
*R3 G_NC $G_NC 1m
.ends
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply. I will try to get a ltSpice Model from Infineon itself :D

Comment: @Till  I'm curious to know how it goes.  Please let me know what happens.

Comment: @Till  I added my own attempt at creating a `BaseComps_LTspice.lib` in case you didn't get anywhere with Infineon.